# I want to give information according to profession using 'Trigger'

Tags: sql, sql-server

'**Trigger**' I want to give information according to the profession using. *For example*; When I entered the engineer I added 'engineer'. This is his name and surname. ' as.

```
ALTER TRIGGER tigger_example
ON information
AFTER INSERT
AS
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE Person_Job='Engineer')
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Engineer added to list.'+
    'Person Info:' +
    'Name : ' + person_firstname + -- not work
    'Surname : ' + person_lastname -- not work
END
ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE Person_Job='Architect')
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Architect added to list.'+
    'Person Info:' +
    'Name : ' + person_firstname + -- not work
    'Surname : ' + person_lastname -- not work
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'An undefined contact has been added to the list.'
END
```

ERROR:

```
The name "person_firstname" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use "SELECT ... from inserted" for read field value.
example:

```
ALTER TRIGGER tigger_example
ON information
AFTER INSERT
AS
DECLARE @MSG NVARCHAR(MAX)
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE Person_Job='Engineer')
BEGIN

    SET @MSG ='Engineer added to list.'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'Person Info:'

    SELECT @MSG=@MSG+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'Name : ' + person_firstname +  'Surname : ' + person_lastname 
    FROM inserted WHERE Person_Job='Engineer'

    print @MSG

END
ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE Person_Job='Architect')
BEGIN

    SET @MSG ='Architect added to list.'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'Person Info:'

    SELECT @MSG=@MSG+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'Name : ' + person_firstname +  'Surname : ' + person_lastname 
    FROM inserted WHERE Person_Job='Architect'

    print @MSG

END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'An undefined contact has been added to the list.'
END
```

Comment: `inserted` can contain multiple rows and, although your code won't ignore them, it may miss or double values. This has been [warned about](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks) for over a *decade*: "all expressions in the SELECT list (including assignments) aren't necessarily run exactly once for each output row"